# Call API WEB with Refit from Webforms Page .Net Frameworks

Tags: c#, refit

I can use Refit from a WebForms Page, to connect with a rest web api method. Some example?

This is my code and I get the following error:

```
protected async void btnAcceder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var api = RestService.For<ILogin>("https://WebApi.Test");
    var login = await api.GetLogin(new Login { UserName = TxtEmail.Text, Password = TxtPassword.Text });
    
    if ( login==null )
    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx?Err=102");
    
    Session["Usuario"] = = login.Token;
    
    Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
}

namespace Dashboard.Sdk
{
using Dashboard.Common.Modelos;
using Refit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

  public interface ILogin
  {
    [Get("/comGpsGate/api/v.1/test#/Tokens")]
    Task<ApiResponse<AuthSuccessResponse>> GetLogin([Body] Login login);
  }
}
```

ERROR

---

Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
No se puede enviar contenido textual con este tipo de verbo.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: No se puede enviar contenido textual con este tipo de verbo.

Error de código fuente:

> Línea 28:  Línea 29:       var api =
> RestService.For("https://WebApi.Test"); Línea 30:       var
> login = await api.GetLogin(new Login { UserName = TxtEmail.Text,
> Password = TxtPassword.Text }); Línea 31:  Línea 32:
>
> Archivo de origen: D:\Desarrollos\Sinergygroup\Dashborad
> GPS\DashBSauro\Login.aspx.cs    Línea: 30
>
> Seguimiento de la pila:
>
> [ProtocolViolationException: No se puede enviar contenido textual con
> este tipo de verbo.]
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckProtocol(Boolean onRequestStream) +556
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback
> callback, Object state) +85
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingRequestStream(RequestState
> state) +129
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.PrepareAndStartContentUpload(RequestState
> state) +311
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Refit.<b__0>d.MoveNext() +708
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> +29    DashBSauro.<btnAcceder_Click>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\Desarrollos\Sinergygroup\Dashborad GPS\DashBSauro\Login.aspx.cs:30
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.<>c.b__6_0(Object state)
> +54    System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0() +15    System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(Action action)
> +89    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +30
> System.Web.UI.d__523.MoveNext() +5878

Comment: Please translate all parts of your question to English.

Comment: Can you add the source code for the ILogin Interface?

Comment: Ok, the code was added.

Comment: did you check this sample project officially provided by the author or `refit` `https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/tree/master/samples`

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/234) issue, that could be connected to your problem. You define the login parameter as [Body]. This is not allowed for get requests. Is it possible, that your login method is a post request instead of a get request or that the parameters should be passed as query parameters instead of a body?